# make excute progress bar

Tags: ajax, jsp, runtime, progress

I use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" method in jsp.

source code...

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "python " + parsing_path+"make.py " + savePath +" " + newFile);

p.waitFor();

but, this command takes about few minutes or hours.

so I want to display progress status.

such as 
1. http://365psd.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Progress_Bar_preview.png

2. https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/3871556/474217822/stock-vector-download-sign-isolated-load-symbol-load-system-data-load-loading-bar-froze-computer-load-icon-474217822.jpg

How can I use this functions.

thanks